# Adeos's role w.r.t Linux

Tags: linux, real-time

> The event pipeline The fundamental Adeos structure one must keep in
>   mind is the chain of client domains asking for event control. A domain
>   is a kernelbased software component which can ask the Adeos layer to
>   be notified of:
>   · Every incoming external interrupt, or autogenerated
>   virtual interrupt; ·
>   Every system call issued by Linux applications, ·
>   Other system events triggered by the kernel code (e.g. Linux task switching, signal notification, Linux task exits etc.).

From: Life with Adeos: http://www.xenomai.org/documentation/xenomai-2.4/pdf/Life-with-Adeos-rev-B.pdf

Question: Adeos is supposed to be between the hardware and the Linux kernel, I can understand about Adeos telling the Linux about hardware interrupts but Why should Adeos know about the "system call" issued by Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux system calls offer direct access to hardware in some cases.  E.g. read() and write() can be applied to raw devices in /dev, ioctl() can be used to poke values into hardware registers.  I assume it is simpler to intercept such activities at syscall time than to anticipate everything a device driver might do and infest it with callbacks.

Comment: yes, thanks, I forgot about "write". Good reminder. So, is it only about the system calls which deal with the hardware? Adeos won't know about the normal system calls issued by Linux?